# How do I serialize objects to include section names and concatenate different object types?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, service

I am sending json to a web service and am turning my code into a mess trying to get it into the expected format with section names...how do I get this structure?:

```
[{"HeaderAttributes": 
    [{
        "recid":"RECHEAD",
        "po_number":"PO001BPTest"
    }]
},      
{"LineAttributes": 
    [{
        "recid":"RECLINE",
        "po_number":"PO001BPTest",
        "line":1,
        "item":"004339"
    }]    
}]
```

My data classes:

```
public class POHeader
{
    private string _recID;
    private string _poNumber;

   [JsonProperty("recid", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string RecID
    {
        get { return _recID; }
        set { _recID = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("po_number")]
    public string PONumber
    {
        get { return _poNumber; }
        set { _poNumber = value; }
    }
}
public class PODetail
{
   private string _recID;
   private string _poNumber;
   private int? _lineNumber;
   private string _itemCode;

   [JsonProperty("recid", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string RecID
    {
        get { return _recID; }
        set { _recID = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("po_number")]
    public string PONumber
    {
        get { return _poNumber; }
        set { _poNumber = value; }
    }
    [JsonProperty("line")]
    public int? LineNumber
    {
        get { return _lineNumber; }
        set { _lineNumber = value; }
    }
    [JsonProperty("item")]
    public string ItemCode
    {
        get { return _itemCode; }
        set { _itemCode = value; }
    }
}
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    private POHeader _headers = new POHeader();
    [JsonProperty("HeaderAttributes")]
    public POHeader POHeaderFields
    {
        get { return _headers; }
        set { _headers = value; }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding these data classes to a parent purchase order class, concatenating, changing IList to List to object, etc.  I've made a mess trying to get it to work. This latest version is concatenating json.  It doesn't work either.

This is the serializing and pushing code:

```
    public static async Task ProcessItemsAsync(object content,  CancellationToken cancellationToken, string path)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "CODE");
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, path))
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

                using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                {
                    request.Content = stringContent;

                    using (var response = await client
                        .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public static async Task TransmitToService(object header, object lines, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string path)
    {
        await TransmitRecordsToIRMS.ProcessItemsAsync(header, lines, cancellationToken, path);
    }
```

Then I basically add data...i've filled it many different ways.  I'm sorry my code is so crazy.

```
   private static void ProcessPOLines(IList records)
    {
        var poLinesToProcess = new List<POHeader>();
        foreach (POOrder record in records)
        {
            // var poDetailList = new List<PODetail>();
             //POHeader poHeader = new POHeader();
              PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder();

            po.POHeaderFields.RecID = RECID;
            po.POHeaderFields.PONumber = record.OrderNbr;

            //poHeader.POHeaderFields.RecID = RECID;
            //poHeader.POHeaderFields.PONumber = record.OrderNbr;

            PODetail poDetail = new PODetail();
            foreach (PXResult<POLine, InventoryItem> line in poLines)  //data selects 
            {
                poDetail.POLineFields.Add(new PODetail
                {
                    RecID = "RECID2",
                    PONumber = record.OrderNbr,
                    LineNumber = pline.LineNbr,
                    ItemCode = iitem.InventoryCD
                });
            }

            TransmitToService(po.POHeaderFields, poDetail.POLineFields, CancellationToken.None, poPath).Wait();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see several confusion here. Let me try to help you. First let's examine your json together:

```
[{"HeaderAttributes": 
    [{
        "recid":"RECHEAD",
        "po_number":"PO001BPTest"
    }]
},      
{"LineAttributes": 
    [{
        "recid":"RECLINE",
        "po_number":"PO001BPTest",
        "line":1,
        "item":"004339"
    }]    
}]
```

- On the top level there is an array of objects:

  - `[{}, {}]`
- On the 2nd level there are objects with only a single property. And that property is an array:

  - `{ "lonelyProperty": []}`
- On the 3rd level there are normal data objects (`PurchaseOrderHeader` and `PurchaseOrderDetail`)

---

Let's try to build it from bottom to top.

#### 3rd level objects

`PurchaseOrderHeader` and `PurchaseOrderDetail` are fine

#### 2nd level object

`PurchaseOrder` could contain

- a property for a `PurchaseOrderHeader`
- a property for collection of `PurchaseOrderDetail`

For example:

```
 public class PurchaseOrder
    {
        [JsonProperty("HeaderAttributes")]
        public PurchaseOrderHeader Header {get; set;}
        [JsonProperty("LineAttributes")]
        public List<PurchaseOrderDetail> Details {get; set;}

    }
```

According to my understanding a `PurchaseOrder` should have only a single header, but correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Now If you serialize an instance of this class then you would see something like this:

```
{
  "HeaderAttributes": 
    {
        "recid":"RECHEAD",
        "po_number":"PO001BPTest"
    },
  "LineAttributes": 
    [{
        "recid":"RECLINE",
        "po_number":"PO001BPTest",
        "line":1,
        "item":"004339"
    }]    
}
```

#### 1st level object

If you want to serialize multiple PurchaseOrders then you can do that for sure. A serialized collection of `PurchaseOrder` would look like this:

```
[
    {
      "HeaderAttributes": 
        {
            "recid":"RECHEAD",
            "po_number":"PO001BPTest"
        },
      "LineAttributes": 
        [{
            "recid":"RECLINE",
            "po_number":"PO001BPTest",
            "line":1,
            "item":"004339"
        }]    
    },
    {
      "HeaderAttributes": 
        {
            "recid":"RECHEAD",
            "po_number":"PO002BPTest"
        },
      "LineAttributes": 
        [{
            "recid":"RECLINE",
            "po_number":"PO002BPTest",
            "line":1,
            "item":"014379"
        }]    
    }
]
```

Is that what you really want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you so much Peter.  I had tried that early on.  But your very well organized answer and question about an array of headers was exactly what I needed.  The third party org that I am pushing data to requires the list of purchase orders with a list of headers and a list of details.  I've never seen that before and it goes against logic and I just couldn't see it.  Once I put my code back to the way it was and turned header into list, it worked.

Comment: @Rowan I'm glad to hear that :D